# How to initialize Mock with variable data

Tags: java, mockito

I have this method to test :

```
public static Date getDateSinceUTC(CstOrderBean orderBean) {

    int year = orderBean.getDeadLineYear();
    int month = orderBean.getDeadLineMonth();
    int day = orderBean.getDeadLineDay();
    int hour = orderBean.getDeadLineHour();
    int minute = orderBean.getDeadLineMinute();
    String ap = orderBean.getDeadLineAmPm() == 1 ? "PM" : "AM";

    //TODO   AM=0, PM=1  comes from html form
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd:hh:mm:aa");
    String stringDate = stringifyIntegers(":", year, month, day, hour, minute); 
    stringDate = stringDate.concat(ap);

    Date date;
    try {
        date = df.parse(stringDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        throw new Error("Parsing date from html form failed", e);
    }
    return date;
}
```

Where CstOrderBean needs to be mocked by Mockito because it is not a POJO (some static initializations etc. - from source code generator). But I need to run the method xxx times, hence set the mocks with many data combinations

I could use TestNG's @DataProvider to do that. But I'm not sure how to do that, I guess that :

```
    when(ob.getDeadLineYear()).thenReturn(1, 2, 3);
     ....
```

in loop is a bad idea, isn't it ? Is the correct way of doing this to create xx mocks and initialize them like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each test should get their own mock that preferably does not have variable data. If you use several different return values from the same mock object then the testing has to be white-box testing as the test is coupled with the number of calls to a mocked method instead of the result of the method under test.

That said, you are able to define a set of return values with calling thenReturn repeatedly or by defining the return values as varargs

```
when(ob.getDeadLineYear()).thenReturn(someValue, anotherValue, ..., ultimateValue);
```

This might be cleaner as you should probably control the values that the mock returns anyway.

Comment: I can't say that I understand what do you mean with the white-box testing. I thought I would pass test method a mock populated like this "do thenReturn(1, 2, 3 ... 100);" and have it tested in a loop(1...100)

Comment: White-box testing refers to the situation where the tester has access to implementation as well as the interface. When you have a mock object that provides multiple results you probably assume that in the implementation the mocked method is called only once. However, if the implementation changes and the method is called multiple times over the tests will break. In this case, you'll have to change the test to reflect the change in implementation (white-box), change the implementation to reflect the test or change them both. In any case, the implementation details leek outside of the interface.

Comment: I see what you mean, this would be an issue in integration testing, this is really just a functional testing of one method, thanks Aleksi

Answer (score 0):

How you mock depends on what you would like to test. Looping on the deadline year might not do the job you want it to.

One test for seeing if a leap year works might be something like:

```
when(ob.getDeadLineYear()).thenReturn(2000);
when(ob.getDeadLineMonth()).thenReturn(2);
when(ob.getDeadLineDay()).thenReturn(29);
when(ob.getDeadLineHour()).thenReturn(12);
when(ob.getDeadLineMinute()).thenReturn(0);
when(ob.getDeadDeadLineAmPm()).thenReturn(1);

assertTrue("Got unexpected date", getDateSinceUTC(ob).toString().startsWith("2000-02-29 12:00:00"));
```

(Warning: above codes was typed in by hand). Mix, match, and repeat for other dates *that you need to test to verify that getDateSinceUTC is working*. You might want a separate test method to check invalid dates, like 2/30/2012 (and expect a throw). You might want to check invalid times like 23:61. You might want to check valid dates, like your birthdate.

Instead of a loop on the year, please look at "normal" cases, borderline cases, and error cases. This is the better practice for unit testing.

Comment: Thanks rajah, but this was a general question on testing with Mocks (one/many instances, variable data). The sample with time was just an example. I guess that one instance and thenReturn(1,2,3 ... 1000); is the proper way of doing that