# Random data generator

Tags: java

I have to fill every property of a given object with a random value.
These are my requirements for it:

- All properties are native Java type (`int`, `double`, `String`, etc)
- I can use reflection
- I can use Spring `DirectFieldAccessor`

I don't want to re-invent the square wheel so I prefer to ask.
For now I came up with this:

Get all properties name with:

```
Field field : myObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()
```

Iterate over those fields and get their class.

Use a giant switch statement for each known native Java type and generate a random value.

What do you think?

Comment: Sounds like fun! Go for it!

Comment: Interesting approach. Like the way you think! :)

Comment: Do you have any field and/or data type specific constraints that your random values must obey to be valid? (E.g. ranges of numerical values, minimum/maximum length of Strings, allowed characters in a String, ...)

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067734/fill-primitive-properties-with-random-data-automatically

Comment: Are you building a [disgruntled bomb](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Disgruntled-Bomb-Java-Edition.aspx) young man/lady?

Answer (score 1):

Another option is [QuickTheories](https://github.com/ncredinburgh/QuickTheories). It looks like:

```
import static org.quicktheories.QuickTheory.qt;
import static org.quicktheories.generators.SourceDSL.*;

public class SomeTests {

  @Test
  public void addingTwoPositiveIntegersAlwaysGivesAPositiveInteger(){
    qt()
      .forAll(integers().allPositive()
          , integers().allPositive())
      .check((i,j) -> i + j > 0); 
  }

  @Test
  public void someTheoryOrOther(){
    qt()
      .forAll(integers().allPositive()
          , strings().basicLatinAlphabet().ofLengthBetween(0, 10)
          , lists().allListsOf(integers().all()).ofSize(42))
      .assuming((i,s,l) -> s.contains(i.toString())) // <-- an assumption
      .check((i,s,l) -> l.contains(i) && s.contains(i.toString()));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with [Instancio](https://www.instancio.org). It's a library that populates objects with random data:

```java
// Returns a fully-populated customer
Customer customer = Instancio.create(Customer.class);
```

The API allows customizing the values:

```java
Customer customer = Instancio.of(Customer.class)
  .generate(field("phoneNumbers"), gen -> gen.collection().size(3))
  .generate(field(Phone.class, "number"), gen -> gen.text().pattern("#d#d#d-#d#d-#d#d"))
  .create();
```

If you use JUnit 5 you can also use it with `@ParameterizedTest` methods:

```
@ExtendWith(InstancioExtension.class)
class ExampleTest {

    @ParameterizedTest
    @InstancioSource(Customer.class)
    void example(Customer customer) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As this is one  [randomizer](https://github.com/android-Infoedge/randomizer) for random data generation.This uses concept of Reflection only as you mentioned.
It  checks annotation mentioned upon field and based on that it checks for Provider class.Go through **Person** model class.
It has some primitive and  non-primitive fo field in that.

```
public class Person {

   @FirstName
   public String mFirstName;

   @LastName
   public String mLastName;

   @Number(min = 14,max = 25,decimals = 0)
   public int age;

   @Email
   public String mEmailId;

   @ReferenceRecord(clazz = Address.class)
   public Address address;

}

@ReferencedRecord
public class Address {

   @StreetAddress
   public String streetAddress;

   @State
   public String state;
}

//Generate random 100 Person(Model Class) object 
Generator<Person> generator = new Generator<>(Person.class);  
List<Person> persons = generator.generate(100);
```

As there are many built in data generator is accessible using annotation,You also can build custom data generator using  **@CustomGenerator** annotation.I suggest you to go through documentation provided on library page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library called [MockNeat](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat) to programatically "fill" your objects with arbitrary data that can pass as "real".

For example in oder to populate an object you can take a look of the [reflect()](https://github.com/nomemory/mockneat/wiki/MockNeat#reflect) method:

```
// Creates a MockNeat object that internally uses
// a ThreadLocalRandom.
MockNeat m = MockNeat.threadLocal();

List<Employee> companyEmployees =
                m.reflect(Employee.class) // The class we are mocking
                 .field("uniqueId",
                        m.uuids()) // Generates a random unique identifier
                 .field("id",
                        m.longSeq()) // Generates long numbers in a sequence
                 .field("fullName",
                        m.names().full()) // Generates a full name for the employer
                 .field("companyEmail",
                        m.emails().domain("company.com")) // Generates a company email with a given domain
                 .field("personalEmail",
                        m.emails()) // Generates an arbitrary email without domain constraints
                 .field("salaryCreditCard",
                        m.creditCards().types(AMERICAN_EXPRESS, MASTERCARD)) // Generate credit card numbers of 'types'
                 .field("external",
                        m.bools().probability(20.0)) // Generates Boolean values with 20% probability of obtaining True
                 .field("hireDate",
                        m.localDates().past(of(1999, 1, 1))) // Generatest a date in the past, but greater than 01.01.1987
                 .field("birthDate",
                        m.localDates().between(of(1950, 1, 1), of(1994, 1, 1))) // Generates a data in the given range
                 .field("pcs",
                        m.reflect(EmployeePC.class) // Mock an EmployeePC object
                         .field("uuid",
                                m.uuids()) // Generates an unique identifier
                         .field("username",
                                m.users()) // Generates an arbitrary username
                         .field("operatingSystem",
                                m.from(new String[]{"Linux", "Windows 10", "Windows 8"})) // Randomly selects an OS from the given List
                         .field("ipAddress",
                                m.ipv4s().type(CLASS_B)) // Generates a CLASS B IPv4 Address
                         .field("macAddress",
                                m.macs()) // Generates a MAC Address
                         .list(2)) // Creates a List<EmployeePC> with 2 values
                 .list(1000) // Creates a List<Employee> with 1000 values
                 .val(); // Returns the list
```

Later edit:

Since my initial answer more ways of generating [data have been added](https://www.mockneat.com/tutorial/#composing-objects).

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Random-JPA](https://github.com/kuros/random-jpa), a framework designed to generate random data. The setup is minimal.

**Usage:**

```
CreationPlan creationPlan = jpaContext.create(
        Entity.of(Employee.class, 2).with(Employee_.Country, INDIA),
        Entity.of(Person.class).with(Person_.gender, "Male"));
```