# How to limit the range of generating numbers in EasyRandom library

Tags: java

EasyRandom library to fill an object with random values

for example:

```java
public EasyRandomParameters getParametersForEasyRandom() {

        final long seedForRandom = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        final int objectPoolSize = 100;
        final int randomizationDepth = 5;
        final int minStringLength = 3;
        final int maxStringLength = 50;
        final int minCollectionSize = 3;
        final int maxCollectionSize = 3;


        EasyRandomParameters parameters = new EasyRandomParameters()
                .seed(seedForRandom)
                .objectPoolSize(objectPoolSize)
                .randomizationDepth(randomizationDepth)
                .stringLengthRange(minStringLength, maxStringLength)
                .collectionSizeRange(minCollectionSize, maxCollectionSize)
                .scanClasspathForConcreteTypes(true)
                .overrideDefaultInitialization(true)
                .ignoreRandomizationErrors(true);


        return parameters;
    }
```

- test

```java
@Test
void givenDefaultConfiguration_thenGenerateSingleObject() {
    EasyRandom generator = new EasyRandom();
    Person person = generator.nextObject(Person.class);

    assertNotNull(person.getAge());
    assertNotNull(person.getFirstName());
    assertNotNull(person.getLastName());
}
```

> Person[firstName='eOMtThyhVNLWUZNRcBaQKxI', lastName='yedUsFwdkelQbxeTeQOvaScfqIOOmaa', age=-1188957731]

While the library is running, it can generate negative values in Integer and Long type fields, and too large a range, how can this be limited, the main thing is that there are no negative values?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
EnhancedRandom enhancedRandom = aNewEnhancedRandomBuilder()
                .randomize(Double.class, new DoubleRangeRandomizer(1, 10))
                .build()
```

Based on the answer here: https://github.com/j-easy/easy-random/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Randomizer<T>`, for example using `BigDecimal` with scale of 9:

```
Randomizer<BigDecimal> randomizer =
        new BigDecimalRandomizer(9, RoundingMode.DOWN);

EasyRandom easyRandom = new EasyRandom(
        new EasyRandomParameters()
            .randomize(BigDecimal.class, randomizer)
);
```

Doc: https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.jeasy/easy-random-core/4.0.0/org/jeasy/random/api/Randomizer.html

Answer (score -3):

easy random documentation doesn't show a way to do it, but you can just change your get methods.
Code person.getAge() to always return java.lang.Math.abs() of whatever has been generated by the library etc.

Comment: A processed class with a huge number of fields and there are many such classes.

Comment: Take a look at one of the other libraries https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067734/fill-primitive-properties-with-random-data-automatically . It may be possible to achieve  what you need easier with them